# Behaviors in sheet content Cannot affect parent View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

It's a sample code , click another view button to change the origin View Text.
Now , everything goes smoothly。

```
    import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView: View {
        @EnvironmentObject var test:Test
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView{
                VStack{
                Text(test.a)
                NavigationLink("change now",destination: editView())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView().environmentObject(Test())
        }
    }

    class Test:ObservableObject{
        @Published var a:String = "Old"
    }

    struct editView:View{
        @EnvironmentObject var test:Test
        var body:some View{
            Button(action:{
                self.test.a = "New"
            }){
                Text("Change !")
            }
        }
    }
```

But， if I move the editView to **.sheet** ，ContentView‘s Text can not be changed!.
in-fact the data has be changed ,but ContentView **not re-render**.

It's a Bug? or any way to solve it ,force the contentView re-render.

```
    import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView: View {
        @EnvironmentObject var test:Test
        @State var show:Bool = false
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView{
                VStack{
                Text(test.a)
                    Button(action:{self.show.toggle()}){
                        Text("show sheet")
                    }
                }
            }.sheet(isPresented: $show){
                editView().environmentObject(Test())
            }
        }
    }

    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView().environmentObject(Test())
        }
    }

    class Test:ObservableObject{
        @Published var a:String = "Old"
    }

    struct editView:View{
        @EnvironmentObject var test:Test
        var body:some View{
            Button(action:{
                self.test.a = "New"
            }){
                Text("Change !")
            }
        }
    }
```

I have done this.

```
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(Test())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was with passing the `EnvironmentObject`. You created a new **Test** model instead of passing the existing one.

```
@EnvironmentObject var test:Test
@State var show:Bool = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack{
            Text(test.a)
            Button(action:{self.show.toggle()}){
                Text("show sheet")
            }
        }
    }.sheet(isPresented: $show){
        editView().environmentObject(self.test)
    }
}
```

Note the last line:

> editView().environmentObject(self.test)

Now it works fine, goodluck!

Comment: Yes! Thanks. and Why .sheet need add .enviromentObject ? .sheet can't get enviroment object from parent without it?

Comment: In some cases you need to pass the EnvObject to the new View because you didn't set the EnvObj in the SceneDelegate.swift. For example: When you want to update the EnvObject in an other View, you need to pass it through in most scenario's. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have add editView().environmentObject(self.test) in SceneDelegate.swift. but not work in sheet.

Comment: No you should only add the EnvObject to the View which is the first responder (the view which will load when the app starts up). From there you need to pass it to Views if necessary. 
In your case: In SceneDelegate.swift, startup ContentView with the EnvObject. From the ContentView pass your EnvObject if needed.